# How to delete oldest file keeping only 5 in a directory?

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

So similar questions have been asked. I want to set a folder, find (backup) files in that folder and keep 5 newest, deleting any older files. Problem I have is that any solutions I've found here only work if the .bat file is in the same folder as the backup files. I would like to set the directory to be different than the one containing the bat file and the amount of files to keep to be a parameter.

I've tried this solution

```
for /F "skip=%NumberOfBackups% eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir "%SNAPSHOTNAME%_PBCS_Test_*.*" /A-D-H /B /O-D 2^>nul') do del "%%I"
```

But setting the NumberOfBackups to 5, and dir to the directory I have, it only works if bat is the same directory. I'm not a bat-expert but I cannot see where I'm going wrong.

Comment: `for /F "skip=5 eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir "C:\Path\To Folder\*" /A-D-H /B /O-D 2^>nul') do del "C:\Path\To Folder\%%I"`. __DIR__ outputs just the file names without path. For that reason the path must be used also on command __DEL__. The wildcard pattern `*` can be also any other wildcard pattern.

Comment: Another possibility is to `cd` or `pushd` "%SNAPSHOTNAME%"` before the loop and just `... ('dir "_PBCS_Test_*.*" ...`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it:

```
@echo off

set NumberOfBackups=5
set SNAPSHOTNAME=Test

pushd "%SNAPSHOTNAME%"
for /F "skip=%NumberOfBackups% eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir *.* /A-D-H /B /O-D 2^>nul') do del "%%I"
```